# "And shadowed on a screen, I saw hooded forms..." - does "shadowed" belong to the "forms"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

Reading Nyarlathotep by H.P. Lovecraft, I would like to ask if my understanding is correct:

> And **shadowed** on a screen, I saw hooded forms amidst ruins, and yellow
> evil faces peering from behind fallen monuments.

As this "fronting" (I do not know how exactly this is called) is not really a concept I am well acquainted with, I am not sure: does it mean "And on the screen, I saw hooded forms (..) shadowed on the screen? If so, what exactly is the meaning of "shadowed" here?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story was written in 1920, so we know that "screen" doesn't refer to a TV screen. Instead it is something more like a movie screen: a curtain onto which light and shadows are being projected.  Indeed, Lovecraft probably could have written "And projected on a screen..." with the similar meaning. But then he would have lost the chance to use a more sinister word "shadow"

A movie projector, or course, works by shining light through a film to create shadows that appear to move. Its not clear if this is literally a movie projector or something more like a shadow puppet show, or something more sinister.  But the narrator initially believes it to be a performance of some kind.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake in the title - it is the word  "shadowed" where I was not sure as for its association. So "shadowed" mean something like "projected on the screen using light and shadows", expressed in my naive English?

Comment: You can edit your question.  Yes, "shadowed" means "projected with shadows", in a somewhat sinister and mysterious style of writing.